# Помогите решить проблему с утечкой памяти в коде C++

Tags: c++, c++17

Помогите решить задачу, проверяющая система на засчитывает задание и выдает ошибку ***Memory leak detected***. Не могу понять, где происходит утечка.

***Условие***

В лекциях мы уже начали реализовывать свой вектор. В этой задаче вам надо его развить: добавить методы `Size`, `Capacity` и `PushBack`. Пришлите на проверку заголовочный файл `simple_vector.h`, содержащий объявление и определение шаблона класса `SimpleVector`:

```
template <typename T>
class SimpleVector {
public:
  SimpleVector() = default;
  explicit SimpleVector(size_t size);
  ~SimpleVector();

  T& operator[](size_t index);

  T* begin();
  T* end();

  size_t Size() const;
  size_t Capacity() const;
  void PushBack(const T& value);

private:
  ...
};
```

Требования:

- метод `Capacity` должен возвращать текущую ёмкость вектора — количество элементов, которое помещается в блок памяти, выделенный вектором в данный момент
- метод `Size` должен возвращать количество элементов в векторе
- метод `PushBack` добавляет новый элемент в конец вектора; если в текущем выделенном блоке памяти не осталось свободного места (т.е. `Size() == Capacity()`), вектор должен выделить блок размера `2 * Capacity()`, скопировать в него все элементы и удалить старый.
- первый вызов метода PushBack для вновь созданного объекта должен делать ёмкость, равной единице
- метод `PushBack` должен иметь амортизированную константную сложность
  методы `begin` и `end` должны возвращать итераторы текущие начало и конец вектора
- в деструкторе должен освобождаться текущий блок памяти, выделенный вектором
  также см. дополнительные требования к работе `SimpleVector` в юнит-тестах в приложенном шаблоне решения

Заготовка решения:
Заготовка `.h` заголовка: [https://d3c33hcgiwev3.cloudfront.net/q-OL4qX_EeilzRLZf2WxfA_ac4e8270a5ff11e89fd0455a8819d387_simple_vector.h?Expires=1595894400&Signature=FJfwZcYJ3BGDSLPvZ-rK0kCjoEIBqVJzttcB2~lB5ktYV66Ne6LRvs272iJGelixzecp1mbwQI62foTVffLgGPqiP0XV8g-t-X-lwHJ--3zPBPrvvAsOR2eOzq2M-AAa7OztFSOyPJGMFWqxSbGvTj5O27T98v7qK0Ic95own84_&Key-Pair-Id=APKAJLTNE6QMUY6HBC5A](https://d3c33hcgiwev3.cloudfront.net/q-OL4qX_EeilzRLZf2WxfA_ac4e8270a5ff11e89fd0455a8819d387_simple_vector.h?Expires=1595894400&Signature=FJfwZcYJ3BGDSLPvZ-rK0kCjoEIBqVJzttcB2%7ElB5ktYV66Ne6LRvs272iJGelixzecp1mbwQI62foTVffLgGPqiP0XV8g-t-X-lwHJ--3zPBPrvvAsOR2eOzq2M-AAa7OztFSOyPJGMFWqxSbGvTj5O27T98v7qK0Ic95own84_&Key-Pair-Id=APKAJLTNE6QMUY6HBC5A)

Заготовка `.cpp` файла: [https://d3c33hcgiwev3.cloudfront.net/uoPvEoauEeianAr0yIdmDg_bae6cec086ae11e88d9327752d64e780_simple_vector.cpp?Expires=1595894400&Signature=H8Va~05CbpyR6meMnAjUtuz8eHsG9ZnZ6oGlS30FLrIqUZIj10teU4DcgNy~aLnAZ2y5eLWXymqTDWHkF6RMsgrnS1uptErbVsRPviV5qWxZkm~qvOnhtgICCcCsrP6pV2YlrGHN0MBSDMYsi60tj5y~VGCDh9sqcftPRPiPBqo_&Key-Pair-Id=APKAJLTNE6QMUY6HBC5A](https://d3c33hcgiwev3.cloudfront.net/uoPvEoauEeianAr0yIdmDg_bae6cec086ae11e88d9327752d64e780_simple_vector.cpp?Expires=1595894400&Signature=H8Va%7E05CbpyR6meMnAjUtuz8eHsG9ZnZ6oGlS30FLrIqUZIj10teU4DcgNy%7EaLnAZ2y5eLWXymqTDWHkF6RMsgrnS1uptErbVsRPviV5qWxZkm%7EqvOnhtgICCcCsrP6pV2YlrGHN0MBSDMYsi60tj5y%7EVGCDh9sqcftPRPiPBqo_&Key-Pair-Id=APKAJLTNE6QMUY6HBC5A)

**Замечание***

Заголовочный файл, который вы пришлёте на проверку, не должен подключать файлы `<vector>`, `<list>`, `<forward_list>`, `<deque>`, `<map>`. Если у вас будет подключен один из этих файлов, вы получите ошибку компиляции.

***Подсказка***

Наверняка в вашей реализации шаблона класса `SimpleVector` будет поле, являющееся указателем. В конструкторе по умолчанию вам надо будет его чем-нибудь проинициализировать. В лекциях мы рассматривали только один способ инициализации указателей — с помощью оператора new. В C++ есть специальное значение, означающее указатель, который ни на что не указывает — `nullptr`:

```
int* p = nullptr;
string* q = nullptr;
map<string, vector<int>>* r = nullptr;
```

Вы можете использовать `nullptr` для инициализации указателя в конструкторе по умолчанию.

А вот мое решение:

```
#pragma once
#include <cstdlib>

using namespace std;

template <typename T>
class SimpleVector {
public:
    SimpleVector() { 
        data = nullptr; 
        end_ = data;
        size_ = 0; 
    }

    explicit SimpleVector(size_t size) {
        //data = (T*) calloc (size, sizeof(T));                     // выделил память под size элементов и заполнить 0
        data = new T[size];
        end_ = data + size;
        size_ = size;
    }

    ~SimpleVector() {
        delete[] data;                                                      // освобождается память
    }

    T& operator[](size_t index) { return data[index]; }

    T* begin() const { return data; }
    T* end() const { return end_; }

    size_t Capacity() const { return end_ - data; }
    
    size_t Size() const { return size_; }

    void PushBack(const T& value) {
        if (size_ == Capacity()) {
            if (size_ == 0) {                                           // для вновь созданного векторы
                //data = (T*) calloc (1, sizeof(T));                        // выделяю память для одного элемента типа T
                data = new T[1];
                data[size_] = value;
                ++size_; 
                end_ = data + size_;
            }
            else {                                                      // если у вектора кол-во полей > 0
                //data = (T*) realloc (data, sizeof(T[2 * Capacity()]));    // расширил область памяти оставив прошлые значения
                T* local_data = new T[size_];
                for (size_t i = 0; i < size_; ++i) {
                    local_data[i] = data[i];
                }
                data = new T[2 * Capacity()];
                for (size_t i =0; i < size_; ++i) {
                    data[i] = local_data[i];
                }
                delete[] local_data;
                data[size_] = value;
                ++size_;
                end_ = data + size_ * 2;
            }
        } 
        else {                                                          // если у вектора уже выделена память под новые поля
            data[size_] = value;
            size_++;
        }
    }
private:
    T *data;
    T *end_;
    size_t size_;
};
```

Собственно у меня проблема в том, что я не могу понять где у меня утечка памяти.

Comment: `data = new T[2 * Capacity()]` - Вы до этого забыли про `delete[]`

Comment: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/rule_of_three

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`data = new T[2 * Capacity()]` - Вы до этого забыли про `delete[]`

(с) Kir_Antipov

Создал прецедент - воспользовался настойчивым [разрешением модераторов переносить комментарии в ответ](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/10628/228791). Более того, я даже указал автора.

Comment: Это неправильный ответ, точнее сильно не полный. Тут целая прорва утечек...

Comment: То есть перед каждым новым выделением памяти надо сначала отчистить ее? Типо если я переопределяю data, сначала надо delete[] data;?

Comment: @user7860670 немного бы вы подсказать где?